# Creating a matrix subset in R

Tags: r, matrix, subset

I have a VERY BIG single row matrix (n=20000):

```
V1  Col1 Col2 Col3 ... Coln
ABC 1    3    5        2
```

I want to subset this to only keep columns with a value >= 3:

```
V1  Col2 Col3
ABC 3    5
```

I have searched everywhere  but cannot come up with a proper solution. I suppose I can transpose it, subset and then transpose back?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical indexing works on either the `i` or `j` arguments to "["

```
Mtx[ , Mtx > 3] # ...............
```

Read and study `?[` carefully. There is so much power in that function that it generally takes about 10 readings to gather all of its capacities and subtleties. (This may eve work on a dataframe of the appropriate construction and the workings of "[" are quite similar for those two structure=types.

Comment: The result is not the same, it now has 1 column, many rows. I need to preserve the structure? I am new to R, apologies if this is a dumb question.

Comment: What happens with: `Mtx[ , Mtx > 3, drop=FALSE]`

Comment: I over thought the solution (hence no answers) and I am not yet good with the basics.